# iPhone SDK: Loading Facebook Connect Login View before everything else

Tags: iphone, facebook

I have a full iPhone application done but I now want to add Facebook Connect. My question is how to load a new/separate view that only has the Facebook Connect button. I need it to be  that the only way they can get into the app is for the Facebook login to be successful. If there is a current active Facebook session then this will no longer load the next time they launch the app.

Where do I begin with the code to put into my AppDelegate?

Answer (score 0):

hey guys if u r facing any prob in Facebook API to connect/login on Facebook then check out this blog.... it will help u alot....

http://viksiphoneblog.blogspot.com/search/label/FBConnect%20API%20for%20Facebook%20Integration

I am also working for the same issue discussed above n I m abt to complete it... in a few days/ hours...

regards,

Vivek Sharma

India

Answer (score -1):

Try to google FacebookAgent...This way, you get the typical pop-up for Facebook to login